# Can I charge a SLA battery with 13v?

Tags: power, batteries, charger

I read somewhere that the minimum voltage is 13.8 V, I would like to know if there is the chance to use 13 V, my SMPS can just offer that, and the cons using this voltage.

Comment: tension = voltage

Comment: "I read somewhere" is a **terrible** source. Please clearly cite your sources. You're very welcome to ask questions here, but why should we prove or disprove a claim that not even you can cite correctly? You could as well ask us to argue for or against "I've read somewhere you need turtles to charge a battery". Reading the source where that was said probably also explains it, and then you wouldn't need to ask at all.

Comment: Some people "read somewhere" that they can charge their phone in a microwave oven. Some of them even try that out ! And then complain that it does not work. Don't be any of these people.

Comment: 73.2% of statements people "read somewhere" are false.  I know because I read that on the internet somewhere.

Comment: hahaha I deserve those reprimend , i should post it , http://www.eleccircuit.com/automatic-battery-charger-circuit/   anyway the laughts worth somehow :) .

Comment: Sure thing! You will never reach 100 % state of charge with just 13 V but if you are fine with that there is no problem. How do you limit the charge current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a circuit that is intended to run from a lead-acid battery, then yes, a 13 V power supply should power it without problems.  As you say, lead-acid batteries are often float charged at around 13.6 V, but are 12 V or less when being discharged.  Since 13 V is well within the expected range of a lead-acid battery, the circuit should be able to work with this voltage.

### Added

I see now that you are asking about charging the battery with 13 V, not running the load with 13 V.

Yes, that will work somewhat, but won't charge the battery optimally.  Any voltage higher than the open-circuit battery voltage will charge it, and 13 V is high enough.  However, it can take a long time to really charge the battery fully.

Take a look at your 13 V power supply carefully.  There may be a output calibration adjustment in it somewhere.  If it's a "13 V" supply (odd value, but we'll go with that), then very likely it can be adjusted up to 13.6 V if there is any adjustment at all.

Another possibility arises if this power supply has a sense input.  It actually adjusts the output to regulate the sense input.  The purpose of a separate sense input (instead of just regulating the output directly) is to allow a remote node to be regulated.  You run a separate wire from that remote node to the sense input, and the remote node will be at the specified voltage.  The power supply puts out a little more as needed to overcome voltage drop in the wires, for example.

If your power supply has a sense input, connect a diode from the output to this sense input, and then some resistance to ground to make sure there is at least a mA or two going thru the diode.  The sense input will be at the output voltage minus the diode drop.  Since the sense input will be regulated to 13 V, you will get about 13.6 or 13.7 V at the output, which is perfect for charging lead-acid batteries.

Comment: I think OP is asking about using 13 V to *charge* the battery, not replace it.

Comment: its a 12 v, i changed the VR to get 13v maximum, is there anyway i could hack the vr to get more? i know there would be some kind of  resist divisor at the output to control pin in the IC but in this smps seems not as easy as i learnt surfing around.

Comment: @Carlos: If you have a schematic and understand it, you can probably hack it to get 13.6 V instead of 13.  Technically this violates design assumptions, so you are still taking a chance making this kind of modification.  If you want to charge lead-acid batteries, it's better to get a "battery charger" power supply rather than try to kludge one that isn't quite meant for the application.

Comment: i will try that, the thing is that i want to charge the battery and in the same time feed my 13 v designed circuit. thanks a lot for the support :)

Comment: @Carlos: Any competently designed circuit meant to be run from a 12 V lead-acid battery while it might be charging should be able to run from 10-14 V *at least*.

Answer (score 0):

*I read somewhere that the minimum voltage is 13.8 volts*

I would say that the **maximum voltage** with which you want to charge a 12 V (nominal) SLA battery is 13.8 V.

When you charge an SLA battery with 13.8 V you can be quite sure that as soon as the battery has reached that 13.8 V, that it will be fully charged.

If you charge it with 13 V it will charge but it might never reach a full charge. This can depend on the actual battery, to know for sure, read the datasheet of that battery.

In general I would say that 13.8 V is a safe upper limit and a good voltage to fully charge an SLA battery.